# Get only empty sub dictionary values from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I have been going at this problem for some time now, it seems that no matter what solution I use, I get the wrong answer.

I have a dictionary such as

```
dict = {'a': {'name': 'Sam', 'likes': 'Cookies'},
        'b': {'name': 'Margaret', 'likes': None},
        'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}
```

What I need to get is

```
{'b': {'likes': None},
 'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}
```

I have tried to use for comprehension to keep it as pythonic as possible

```
>>>{subd:{key:value for key,value in dict[subd].items() if not value} for subd in dict}


{'a': {},
 'b': {'likes': None},
 'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}
```

I understand that I am getting 'a' in the output since I am iterating through each sub dictionary and it does have all values in the parameters so the result is an empty {}, how can I ensure to skip subdictionaries if they dont have any empty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Please refrain from using built in names, such as `dict`. These will usually lead to breaking code.
- A dictionary comprehension, is only pythonic if the purpose remains clear. Using nested dictionary comprehensions, is usually not more readable than two separate lines.

In this case you only have two depth levels, so it would suffice to have two loops, where you only have to check if the final dictionary does not contain empty key values:

```
data = {'a': {'name': 'Sam', 'likes': 'Cookies'},
        'b': {'name': 'Margaret', 'likes': None},
        'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}

def get_none(dictionary):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        result[key] = {k: v for k, v in value.items() if v is None}
    return {k: v for k, v in result.items() if v}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_none(data))
```

Resulting in:

```
{'b': {'likes': None}, 'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}
```

### Edit

I changed the

```
dictionary = dictionary.copy()
```

line to a new dictionary called `result`. By doing this, I don't copy any large dictionary unnecessary.

Comment: Please refrain from modifying the given dict in addition to returning a new one. That will usually lead to breaking code :-P

Comment: I thought about it while constructing the solution, that I should mention that, of course I forgot... Thanks for the catch. I edit the code by creating a local copy, such that the original dictionary isn't altered.

Answer (score 0):

you can this code:

```
dict = {'a':{'name': 'Sam', 'likes': 'Cookies'}, 'b':{'name': 'Margaret', 'likes': None}, 'c':{'name': None, 'likes': None}}
dic = {}
for elem in dict.keys():
    dict_n = dict[elem]
    di = {k: v for k, v in dict_n.items() if v is None}
    res = {elem:di}
    if di != {}:
        dic.__setitem__(elem,di)
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'b': {'likes': None}, 'c': {'name': None, 'likes': None}}
```

**setitem**  method to add a key-value pair to a dict

Answer (score 0):

```
{k: nones
 for k, d in dct.items()
 if (nones := {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v is None})}
```